# My text file lines sometimes contain the same string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a text file which contains the same string of characters in different lines. I read the file using this code:

```
Dim readTexte() As String = File.ReadAllLines(OuvrirFichier, Encoding.UTF8)
Dim t As String
For Each t In readTexte
    If t.Contains(TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text) Then
        TextBox2.Text = Trim(t.Substring(0, 18))
        TextBox1.Text = Trim(t.Substring(18, 90))
        TextBox4.Text = Trim(t.Substring(107, 120))
    End If
Next
```

However, I have a problem because when cutting and reading these strings. The code is not able to choose the right line to match the TreeView node, because it identifies several equally perfect strings.

For example, the first line contains 3 substrings (fixed width fields):

> Saint, Augustine, and Doctor of the Church.

The second line contains three sub-strings as well, slightly different:

> Saint, Monica, and mother of Saint Augustine

When I want to read, my code gives me two Augustines, and mixes Augustine and Monique! The TextBox2 contains the string contained in the treeview.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

The treeview is created as simply as possible, thus:

```
Dim readText () As String = File.ReadAllLines (OpenFile,
Encoding.UTF8)
              Dim s As String
              For Each s In readText
                  TextBox2.Text = Trim (s.Substring (0, 18))
                  TextBox1.Text = Trim (s.Substring (18, 90))
                  TextBox4.Text = Trim (s.Substring (107, 120))
                  Dim node As TreeNode = Me.TreeView1.Nodes (0)
                  TreeView1.Nodes (0) .Nodes.Add (New TreeNode (TextBox1.Text))
              Next
```

Comment: You could try splitting on the comma and then see if any of the items in the array matches your node.  Just a guess since we don't know the consistency of your data.

Comment: @LarsTech That's my fault. I misread the question at first and had a bad edit (better now). But the idea to pre-parse things is dead on.

Comment: The code is both structured and text files based. I enter data in a library from UTF8 encoded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to know more about how the TreeView is built before we can answer this. It's possible there is simply not enough data associated with the TreeView right now, and the solution will be in a completely different area of the code.

However, I can provide some notes. First, reading a file is one of the slowest things possible to do in a computer. We already see this is small enough to fit in memory; if it's also reasonably stable (doesn't change often), you can save significant work by loading to the array *once* when the program starts.

Next, I wouldn't keep just a simple array of strings. Instead, I'd parse the data into separate fields right at load. A Tuple, Class, or even string array can all work.

Finally, this code will continue looping even after if finds a match. I'd have a way to stop once we find what we're looking for.

Put it all together like this:

```
'Create a set of Tuples. Could also use a class here.
Dim readTexte() As IEnumerable(Of (String, String, String)) = 
    File.ReadLines(OuvrirFichier, Encoding.UTF8).
        Select(Function(line) (Trim(line.SubString(0, 18)), Trim(line.SubString(18,90)), Trim(line.SubString(107,120))) )
             

'Search the collection for the first match             
Dim result = readTexte.First(Function(record) TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.Equals(record.Item1))
TextBox2.Text = result.Item1
TextBox1.Text = result.Item2
TextBox4.Text = result.Item3
```

Again, this doesn't solve your matching problem, because the question doesn't contain the information we need to help do that. Please *edit the question* to include more details on how the TreeView is created.

Comment: Dim result = readText.First (Function (record) TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = record.Item1)
         TextBox2.Text = result.Item1
         TextBox1.Text = result.Item2
         TextBox4.Text = result.Item3
This throws me an error: 'Item1' is not a member of 'IEnumerable (Of (String, String, String))'.

Comment: `result` should be a tuple with strings, but somehow it's getting picked up as an IEnumerable. Do you have Option Strict and Option Infer on? You're probably missing a `Using` directive and seeing this message instead of the correct message because of a bad decision on Option Strict

Comment: Option Strict is set to Off but if I set it to ON, I have a hundred errors that occur! Option Infer is of course On.

Comment: `Option Strict is set to Off but if I set it to ON, I have a hundred errors that occur! ` good, then it's doing its job; (it's best to turn the option on at the project level). When `Option Strict On`, it restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type [read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)

Comment: You should take the time to fix those errors! Every single one is a potential for your program to break at run time.

Comment: Strict option on ON, I am currently making the error corrections. So far that's okay. Thank you. Claude. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: After resolving everything from Option Strict to On, I get four errors: Item1, Item1, Item2 and Item3 are not members of 'IEnumerable (Of (String, String, String))'

Comment: You've mistyped something. The error is correct, in that `Item1` is a member of a Tuple, not a collection of Tuples. But both `First()` and the lamdba predicate remove the collection, so you're looking at one member.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how I should do it.

Comment: @claudebl I have a demo of it working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ykT3I

Comment: Thanks Joel, I was finally able to fully understand how your work works. Claude :)